# how can i print increasing number value on every click inside divs?

Tags: javascript

how can i print increasing number value on every click inside divs?

[here my divs that i want to insert numbers on every click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM5eL.png)

```
for(let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {

document.getElementById("grid-item").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("grid-item").innerHTML = i;
}


</div>
<div class="grid-container" id="grid-container-item">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item1" id="grid-item1" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item2" id="grid-item2" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item3" id="grid-item3" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item4" id="grid-item4" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item5" id="grid-item5" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item6" id="grid-item6" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item7" id="grid-item7" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item8" id="grid-item8" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item9" id="grid-item9" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item10" id="grid-item10" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let index = 1;
let last_element = undefined;
let last_value = undefined;
function myFunction(element) {
    last_value = element.innerHTML;
    element.innerHTML = index++;
    last_element = element;
}

document.getElementById("reset_all").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-item');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
      element.innerHTML = '';
      index = 1;
  });
})

document.getElementById("undo").addEventListener("click", function(){
   if (!last_element)
     return;
   last_element.innerHTML = last_value;
   index--;
   last_element = undefined;
});
```

```css
.grid-item
{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#reset_all
{
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
}
#undo
{
  background-color: lime;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container" id="grid-container-item">
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item1" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item2" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item3" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item4" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item5" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item6" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item7" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item8" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item9" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item10" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
</div>

<br>
<div id="reset_all">Reset All</div>
<div id="undo">Undo</div>
```

did you mean it? if yes, tell me to explain it...

Comment: Thanks but i want something like that: for first click its: 1, and for second click to another cell is: 2, and 3, and 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works! Then, can i ask two more questions? How can reset all changes by a button and undo last change by a button?

Comment: @bunubicom I edited my post, if you only want user can undo just one time, otherwise you must use `Stack`

Comment: Thank you. But your solution works here, but not in browser :( I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')" error. What can I do?

Comment: @bunubicom did you add `<div id="reset_all">Reset All</div>
<div id="undo">Undo</div>` to your `html` file?

Comment: yes i did. here: https://codepen.io/dryasinyildiz/pen/JjpGOBd

Comment: @bunubicom move `<script>` tag to after`</body>` tag

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then you can do something like seen inside of this:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  e.innerHTML = (parseInt(e.innerHTML) || 0) + 1;
  // console.log(e.innerHtml)
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container" id="grid-container-item">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item1" id="grid-item1" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item2" id="grid-item2" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item3" id="grid-item3" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item4" id="grid-item4" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item5" id="grid-item5" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item6" id="grid-item6" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item7" id="grid-item7" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item8" id="grid-item8" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item9" id="grid-item9" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item10" id="grid-item10" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>
</div>
```

Passing `this` into the function called by `onclick` passes in the element that the property is found. Meaning that the function will always run the code correct to the clicked on function.

Comment: Thanks but i want something like that: for first click its: 1, and for second click to another cell is: 2, and 3, and 4.

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y5sgu91p/16/) JSFiddle answer your question?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work competely :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't think we are quite fully understanding each other, I have a feeling the other answers solve your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

A modern approach would be to strip out all of the inline JS from the HTML, and use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch events from the container's child elements.

The listener calls a function that initialises a count (no need for global variables), and then returns a *new* function ([a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)) that will act as the handler for the click listener. When it's returned it carries with it a copy of `count`.

```js
// Select the container
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

// Attach one listener to it
// We call `handleClick` which returns a new function
// that is called when the listener is fired. It
// carries with it its own local copy of `count`.
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false);

// `handleClick` initialises `count` and then
// returns a new function that is called when the
// container is clicked. When it is clicked it checks
// to see if the clicked element has an "item" class
// and then it updates its text content with
// an incremented `count`.
function handleClick() {
  let count = 0;
  return function (e) {
    if (e.target.matches('.item')) {
      e.target.textContent = ++count;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container { display: grid; width: 210px; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 60px); grid-gap: 10px; }
.item { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 60px; height: 60px; font-size: 1.4em; background-color: black; color: white; }
.item:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i want something like that: for first click its: 1, and for second click to another cell is: 2, and 3, and 4.

Comment: Is my update closer to what you want? @bunubicom